# iOS Objective-C UIBarButtonItem Set Selector

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm creating a UIBarButtonItem as such to create a back button:

```
self.backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backToolbar];
self.backButton.enabled = YES;
self.backButton.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

I'd like to set it's selector as such:

```
- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"goBack pushed");

    [self.iframeView goBack];
}
```

What's the best way to set the backButton to have a selector of `goBack`?

EDIT:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *backButton;
```

Comment: What is backToolBar ? A UILabel/ UIButton ?

Comment: Updated my question. It's just a UIBarButtonItem

Comment: Is there any reason you passing `backButton` (which is already a bar button) to another `UIBarButtonItem`? Have you do something like `[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:@selector(self) action:@selector(goBack:)];`

Comment: What's wrong with simply setting the `action` property to `@selector(goBack:)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is directly assigning to bar button item like

```
[backButton setTarget:self];
[backButton setAction:@selector(backButtonPressed:)];
```

Second way a initiating bar button item with a button which has already a action

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 60.0, 30.0)];
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(backButtonPressed:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```